Best Way to Refresh Excel Tabs in SSIS
I have several projects that pull data from a client's server into Excel files, processes them, and then updates the output Excel files.
Currently I have several dozen Script Tasks, and I designate the file and timeout in each file, and each one may be different, and of course, I don't know how long I need until I try it and it doesn't work.
My code is as follows:
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
#endregion

namespace ST_5b129430179446449b528cfa97b05e80
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Refreshes all sheets/tabs in an Excel file
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                            
            /// Path and Filename of Excel file
            string fileName = @"C:\OneDrive\Projects\Client\Data\Customers.xlsx";   

            Excel.Application m_objExcel;
            Excel.Workbooks m_objBooks;
            Excel.Workbook m_objBook;

            try
            {
                m_objExcel = new Excel.Application();
                m_objBooks = (Excel.Workbooks)m_objExcel.Workbooks;
                m_objBook = (Excel.Workbook)m_objBooks.Open(fileName,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing);
                /// Time needed to open file, increase for large files
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                m_objBook.RefreshAll();
                /// Time needed to refresh and save Excel file
                Thread.Sleep(5000);     

                m_objBook.Save();
                m_objBook.Close();
                m_objExcel.Quit();

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I am catching the error");

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("C:\\OneDrive\\Projects\\Client\\Data\\Logs\\" + "Customers_ErrorLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyMMddHHmmss") + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                m_objBook = null;
                m_objBooks = null;
                m_objExcel = null;

                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}

Using RefreshAll() and Thread.Sleep(x) are the only way I've found to pause the script while Excel opens and refreshes.  I am amazed that there isn't an easier way to wait until Excel is ready and/or completed the task.
Is there a better method to do this?
